# How to pass table name as parameter in OleDB?

Tags: c#, oledb

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string tablename = label2.Text;
        string name = TextBox1.Text;
        DBconnection.savetodb(tablename, name);           

}
```

I call the method below from another form to save the name into a specific table. But it wont save into my table in database.

```
public static void savetodb(string tablename, string name)
{
        OleDbConnection connection = GetConnection();
        string query = String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} (Name) VALUES (@Name)", tablename);

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);

        try{
            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Console.WriteLine("Exception catch", ex);
        }
        finally{
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: What do you mean by _wont save_? You get any exception or error message? Did you debug your code as well?

Comment: The name is not save into my microsoft access table. i din't get any exception error message, yes i have debug my code.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing table name as a parameter, you are passing your `@Name` value as a parameter. You can't pass a table name as a parameter *even* if you want. Parameters only for values, not table or column names. You are just formatting your query based table name. As far as I see, your problem using named parameters. OleDb provider does not support named parameters.

From [`OleDbCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example:
>
> SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
>
> Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the
>   OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of
>   the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

Try it as;

```
string query = String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} (Name) VALUES (?)", tablename);
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
```

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand`.

```
using(OleDbConnection connection = new GetConnection())
using(OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{

}
```

And consider to use [`.Add` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead `.AddWithValue`. It may cause some problems. Read [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: i have retype my code above without changing anything and this time it work. i think there are something wrong with my visual studio 2013. but still thanks for your help, it improve my knowledge, I am still a beginner on C# :)